# How to make browser NOT parse new HTML code that added from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ajax

I want to add some text to my webpage from my server with ajax, but the text includes some html tags, and browsers tend to parse that code and render it. I don't want this behavior, i want to appent that text without parsing the html tags.
Is there way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using PHP? See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: no, the project running on asp.net, but is there a javascript way of doing this?

Comment: how do you add the returned text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to *encode* the returned "HTML". basically you have to replave `<`, `>` and `&` with `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`.

if you're using PHP on serverside, for example, you could do this using [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) - there might be similar functions or methods available for other languages ([cgi.escape](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape) for python, [HTML:Entities](http://search.cpan.org/%7Egaas/HTML-Parser-3.69/lib/HTML/Entities.pm) for Perl, [System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) for asp.net ...).

if you do this on a retuned string that looks like

```
this is <strong>bold</strong> text
```

wich is shown in your browser as

> this is **bold** text

your output will change to

```
this is &lt;strong&gt;bold&lt;/strong&gt; text
```

wich will display as

> this is <strong>bold</strong> text

Answer (score 2):

Use [`node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent) property (element.innerText on IE<=8) to assign *textual* content to an element. Browser will encode all special characters into the respective HTML entities:

```
var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
if (typeof h1.textContent != "undefined") {
    h1.textContent = "<b>Hello World</b>";
}
else if (typeof h1.innerText != "undefined") {
    h1.innerText = "<b>Hello World</b>";
}
alert(h1.innerHTML);​
// at this point, the h1 tag will "render" <b>Hello World</b>
// not the text Hello World in bold face
// inspecting the element will reveal that html tags, e.g. <b>
// were converted to &lt;b&gt;
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/wZxVJ/)

Comment: some explanation on this might be useful as gkaykck might not knew how/why this works and how to apply this to his/her own code.

Comment: I've added a demo that shows how to add HTML content literally to an element.

Answer (score 0):

In browser-side javascript:

```
function htmlEncode( str )  {
    str = str + "";
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.appendChild( document.createTextNode( str ) );
    return el.innerHTML;
}

htmlEncode( "<div></div>" );
//"&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"
```